# Linking unreferenced libraries breaks my program

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker

I have a post-processing program that interfaces with Abaqus. The program works fine with Abaqus 6.9 EF1. I want to update the program to work with Abaqus 6.12. I have not had any luck with getting the program to work with the updated API.

I have updated the list of libraries to link with in Visual Studio 2010. Everything builds and links properly. When I run the program, I get the following message before hitting `main`:

[image: Error message]

Since the program is big (>120k lines), I decided to go back to basics. The simple program below runs fine until I call `delete`. Once I call `delete`, I get the same error message. If I do not link to the Abaqus libraries, the program completely runs.

```
#include <iostream>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;

    int *p;
    p = new int(3);
    std::cout << *p << std::endl;
    delete p;

    return 0;
}
```

To Clarify:

**Case 1**: Not linking to Abaqus libraries. Runs fine.

**Case 2**: Linking to Abaqus libraries. Throws Debug Assertion Failed message.

**Bottom line**: I do not understand how linking but *not using* their libraries breaks the simple program.

In my previous problems with Abaqus, I have convinced myself that they have created their own `new` and `delete` operators. Could their version of `new` be called while the standard version of `delete` is called? If so, it their a way to resolve the scope of these functions?

Comment: Try `::new` and `::delete` and see what it does.

Comment: The error being in `dbgdel.cpp` certainly suggests that the problem is occurring in `operator delete`, and the path seems to point to the Microsoft version. Try stepping with the debugger into the `new` and see where it goes.

Comment: @Mahesh Thank you for your suggestion. I get the same results using `::new` and `::delete`. If there are two new functions in the global namespace, do I have any options? I'll dig around in the API to see if there actually is a `new` function defined by Abaqus.

Comment: @PeteBecker I have tried stepping into the `new` function, but Visual Studio jumps over it.

Comment: I was afraid of that. It's been several years since I used Microsoft tools, but there **is** a tool that you can run on your executable to see what external symbols it links to (it might be `objdump`, but I'm not at all confident of that). Find `operator new` and `operator delete` and see which DLL they're coming from. If they're in two different DLLs that's probably the source of the problem.

Comment: I can confirm that Abaqus defines `new` and `delete` operators. In fact, they have at least two different sets. One set is for larger classes and the other set is for smaller classes. I don't see that they have wrapped them in a namespace.

Comment: Although, their `new` and `delete` operators are kept within a class, so they shouldn't hide the `::new` and `::delete` operators.

Comment: *linking but not using* - are you sure about this? I mean, if you create new project, do not include **any** Abaqus header, just add Abaqus library as the last library to link against in Linker options - will there be the same problem?

Comment: @izogfif Yes, I'm sure about it. Also, I was able to verify that the call to `operator new` is linked to an Abaqus .dll. This explains my problem. I tried switching the order, but I'm not sure it matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that Abaqus defines their own `operator new` and `operator delete` in the *global namespace*. Thus, I was unknowingly linking to their implementation of `operator new`.

However, Visual Studio is linking to the Abaqus definition of `operator new` and *not* to the Abaqus definition of `operator delete`. Instead, Visual Studio is linking to the standard definition of `operator delete`.

These functions cannot be used interchangably, so I receive the error message. However, because Abaqus placed their `operator new` and `operator delete` functions in the global namespace, I believe that I have no control over which function gets linked.

---

Update: The above is only partially correct. Abaqus does define their own `operator new` but they do **not** define a matching `operator delete` -- at least in the global namespace.

Thus, Visual Studio cannot link to the corresponding Abaqus `operator delete` because it does not exist.